# php: get text of <a> tag having another tag inside it

Tags: php, html, regex

```
<a href="http://corporate.mattel.com/privacy-policy.aspx" class="privacy">
    <b>Primary Text</b> Secondary Text
</a>
```

I need text of  tag means, output should be "**Primary Text** Secondary Text".

Please help to build a regular expression to fulfill this purpose.

Currently, I am using following regex :-

```
$regex = "/<a[\s]+[^>]*?href[\s]?=[\s\"\']+"."(.*?)[\"\']+.*?>"."([^<]+|.*?)?<\/a>/";
```

This regex gives me an correct output for :-

```
<a href="http://corporate.mattel.com/privacy-policy.aspx" class="privacy">
    Primary Text
</a>
```

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: This my specific requirement and I need regex. Currently, I am using /<a[\s]+[^>]*?href[\s]?=[\s\"\']+"."(.*?)[\"\']+.*?>"."([^<]+|.*?)?<\/a>/.
But it is discarding text value if it has any tag inside it.

Comment: I would concur with Jay that you should change the requirement to do it without regexes, even if it means telling your superior he's an idiot **;)** [This website](http://htmlparsing.com/) explains why.

Comment: [If the requirement is to draw a red line with a green pen, it's hard to achieve...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't parse html with regex, use php `DOM Parser` instead.
To remove the `b` tag use `strip_tags`, i.e.;

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.website.php");
/* 
OR 
$html = '<a href="http://corporate.mattel.com/privacy-policy.aspx" class="privacy">
    <b>Primary Text</b> Secondary Text
</a>';
*/
# Create a DOM parser object
$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$urls = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($urls as $url) {
   $url->nodeValue = strip_tags($url->nodeValue);
} 
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```